# Challenging Integration Problem

Tags: integration

I have the following indefinite integral which I am trying to solve. I have provided some of my efforts below.

\begin{equation}
 f(t) = \int\frac{\Gamma(0,t^2) \cos(t)}{\ln t} \,dt
\end{equation}

As you will see, I apply integration by parts over and over again and thereby secure additional terms outside of the integral. Unfortunately, this approach requires the successive determination of higher-order derivatives. I would suspect there is a way to do this but it has eluded me.

Preliminary work:
Using integration by parts, we obtain:

\begin{align}
u &= \frac{\Gamma\left(0,t^2\right)}{\ln t} && && && && v = \sin(t)\\
\\
du &= -\frac{\Gamma(0,t^2)}{t(\ln t)^2} -\frac{2e^{-t^2}}{t\ln t} && && && && dv = \cos(t)
\end{align}

Since, $\int u \,dv = uv - \int v \,du$, we arrive at:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(0,t^2)}{\ln t} \sin(t) + \int \left( \frac{\Gamma(0,t^2)}{t(\ln t)^2} +\frac{2e^{-t^2}} {t\ln t}\right) \sin(t) \,dt
\end{equation}

Next, assign $u_\text{new} = du_\text{old}$ and $dv_\text{new} = v_\text{old}$ and repeat the process.

I realize there may be no good approach to this, but I thought I would ask.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this indefinite integral can be expressed in terms of the usual zoo of special functions?

Comment: I am seeing the beginning of reoccurring behavior and I thought that perhaps a technique similar to those with trig functions might work. However, I have not yet stumbled upon a way to do that, if that way exists at all.